# how to ignore empty values from mysql in python to fill a list?

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

So i have a database with the table person and person has characteristics 1-5.

we fill the person table with data, we can add up to 5 characteristics, but that is not necessary

So now i want to write every person in a list with their characteristics, but if the characteristics are empty, those wont be seen. 
the result in then printed out to me.

i can now give out the list with the persons, but i still see the empty values.

Someone have an idea to exclude the empty values, via sql or python?

edit

```
#we fetch the result and then write it into the lists
SQLdeckung = 'Select * from Ergebnis_Compare
deckungCursor.execute(SQLdeckung)
    result_update = deckungCursor.fetchall()
    for i in result_update:
        neueTabelleResult.append(i[0])
        neueTabelleResult.append(i[1])
        neueTabelleResult.append(i[2])
        neueTabelleResult.append(i[3])
        neueTabelleResult.append(i[4])
        neueTabelleResult.append(i[5])
    deckungCursor.execute(dropNeueTabelle)


except pysql.MySQLError as err:
    print('Fehler in DeckungsCalc' , err)

connection.commit()
deckungCursor.close()
#here we want to print out the result
messagebox.showinfo('Dies ist die Deckungsliste:', neueTabelleResult)
```

Comment: Totally unanswerable without code. Do you `commit()` the changes?

Comment: added code @roganjosh

Comment: Why don't you check whether `i[x]` is null/empty before appending to `neueTabelleResult`?

Answer (score 0):

You should filter the data in the SQL statement. For example:

`SELECT * FROM Ergebnis_Compare WHERE <column-name> IS NOT NULL`

Where `<column-name>` is the column that contains the person's characteristics.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether every item in a record is empty/None before inserting into `neueTabelleResult`:

```
for rec in result_update:
    for item in rec:
        if item is not None and item.strip() != '':
            neueTabelleResult.append(item.strip())
```